# SVG Security on WordPress vs. without cms

Tags: wordpress, security, svg

I understand that it is a risk to use SVG and Wordpress disable the use of them. But many website nowadays use SVG because of the performance and resolution. So are all these websites having a huge risk to get hacked?

If I would code the website in plain html, css, php, mysql without a cms, would my website be highly risked to get hacked too?

Comment: How did you come to such an understanding?

Comment: @RobertLongson There are many articles on SVG being insecure and that is the reason WordPress unabeld the possibility to upload them out of the box. F.e. this is a often refereed to article: https://bjornjohansen.no/svg-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are effectively (XML) text that are interpreted and rendered by the browser. The **SVG "text" can include scripts** (for valid or malicious reasons). SVG has a lot of benefits. I use animated SVG headers that I created myself on my Wordpress sites; file are small and do not rely on JavaScript for animation.

I assume you are ONLY talking about having your OWN SVG images for the header, or in your own posts (and won't be including malicious scripts to attack you or your visitors!). If so, in my fallible opinion, there should be near Zero (can never say never) risk as long as you cater for these possibilities:

1. you use an SVG file created by someone else that contains malicious code. So **create your own, or obtain them from one of the major image sites and check the SVG source text carefully before use**.
2. a visitor/user uploads (innocently or otherwise) a poisoned SVG. Even if it is not displayed on your site the simple act of you viewing (say via Cpanel) the uploaded file in a browser could trigger the malicious payload. So **block anyone else from uploading SVGs**. Ideally upload your own via FTP and block all uploads via your site's pages.

see also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/247190/128374

Comment: So, the point is that the SVG I upload (exported from photoshop of my designer) are secure and can not be chaged by others normally. Only if I allow upload of SVGS files from other, that might be a security issue? Did I got you right?

Comment: If the SVGs are used as images, no scripts in them will run.

Comment: Yes - don't allow other users to upload SVGs. If I trusted my designer I would be happy to use their custom SVGs on-site. Also see Robert Longson's comment that SVGs in `<img>` tags won't run scripts.

Comment: @Robert Longson thanks for the heads up on use as img. I had read they were a risk - but on rechecking now I see they should be safe (and img execution in v old Browsers (Opera?) have been fixed).